# I can have two main function in two static library of C++ when I link both of them?

Tags: c++, linker, program-entry-point

I have three files:

test.cpp (it is empty) :

main1.cpp

```
int main()
{
    printf("main_1\n");
    return 0;
}
```

main2.cpp

```
int main()
{
    printf("main_2\n");
    return 0;
}
```

then I create two static library **main1.a** and **main1.a**.

g++ -c main1.cpp

ar r main1.a main1.o

g++ -c main2.cpp

ar r main2.a main2.o

I found that the output will different depends on the order of **main1.a** and **main2.a** as

- **main1.a** is in front of **main2.a**

  $ g++ -o out test.cpp **main1.a** main2.a

  $ ./out

  the output is "main_1"
- **main2.a** is in front of **main1.a**

  $ g++ -o out test.cpp **main2.a** main1.a

  $ ./out

  the output is "main_2"

why it will not have the error message "multiple definition of `main'" as the command?:

g++ -o out test.cpp main1.cpp main2.cpp

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, thanks for your reply. so does it mean the error message is generated at compile stage?

Comment: No, it happens at linking stage. The linker just uses different rules for object files and static libraries. First is “include all”, second “include what you couldn’t find in the object files and take the first matching one”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker handles these two cases very differently (by default). When compiling code into object files and linking them the linker will not allow two strong definitions to exist. Strong here is for example a function or a variable with a set value. It will allow one strong and multiple weak ones (like a variable with a set value in one object and another with the same variable but no set value).

With static libraries the linker goes through them in the order they’re given. It looks up the exports, if any of them are needed by the other linked objects it takes it in and restarts the process in that file (to find the functions the just found function possibly needs). So in this process when it gets to the first library it checks for its exports, sees `main`, determines it’s needed and takes it in. Then it goes to the second library, sees `main`, doesn’t see it in the list of undefined symbols and just skips it.

More information can be found on [Eli Bendresky’s website](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking)